# Adapter Methods in Android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i have go through the three methods in Adapters classes.

1. getView()
2. newView()
3. bindView()

what are the difference between those methods? please share some tutorial, sample code or logics to understand this. Thanks. i have to create a listview with the progressive icons. which adapter you suggest me to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getView()` returns the `View` for a row. For a custom subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, you typically override `getView()`.

For a custom subclass of `CursorAdapter`, you *could* override `getView()`, but usually you override `newView()` and `bindView()` instead. `newView()` creates the row View and `bindView()` attaches the data for the specific position in the `Cursor`'s data set to that row.

These concepts are covered (with more emphasis on `getView()`) in this [excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books.

Comment: you didnt answer for this part of my question "i have to create a listview with the progressive icons. which adapter you suggest me to do that?"

Comment: That's because the question does not make sense. You can use any adapter you want -- "progressive icons", whatever those are, do not enter into your decision as to what adapter you use.